# How to use convolutions of pictures instead of FC layers?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, transposed-convolution

How to use convolutions of pictures instead of FC layers?

How can i do this effectively and efficiently.

Comment: What are you asking for, an example in a programming language? The R keras webpage has some nice examples with and without convolution.

Comment: Explain more what you mean, this is very vague!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conv2d from tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d) for this. You can find [here](https://github.com/Mathhead/Lessons-in-Machine-Learning/blob/master/lesson_0019_mnist_classification_convolutional_neural_network_2.ipynb) an example where convolutional layers are used to classify handwritten digits.